# Evenly distributed random in Bash

Tags: bash, random

I've been using "shuf" and "sort -R" to shuffle my music playlist, but it feels like certain songs get played more than others.

To test this, I used the following command which shuffles the alphabet and records the 1st letter in the shuffle, repeated x1000 and then counts the number of times each letter was picked. If it were truly random there would be an even distribution, but it's always lop-sided:

```
printf "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh\ni\nj\nk\nl\nm\nn\no\np\nq\nr\ns\nt\nu\nv\nw\nx\ny\nz" > alphabet.txt; for i in {1..1000}; do cat alphabet.txt | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle(<STDIN>);' | perl -e 'print reverse <>' | head -1 >> results.txt; done; sort results.txt | uniq -c | sort; rm results.txt; rm alphabet.txt
```

Which results in something like:

> ```
>  29 w
>  30 u
>  31 d
>  32 i
>  33 v
>  34 c
>  34 m
>  36 a
>  36 g
>  36 k
>  36 n
>  36 r
>  36 z
>  38 y
>  39 x
>  40 b
>  40 e
>  40 o
>  42 p
>  43 f
>  43 h
>  43 s
>  44 j
>  44 l
>  52 q
>  53 t
> ```

Notice how 't' was selected 53 times, but 'w' only 29. I believe the songs I hear most often are like the 't', and there are songs I rarely get in the mix (like the 'w').

Can anyone come up with a Bash/Perl/Python/etc command that would/could distribute the random results more evenly?

Comment: ...mind you, I'd need to run some statistics to know if your results (above) actually *do* reflect any kind of a bug; it's not at all clear that they do. If you run another thousand, do you have the same letters favored and disfavored?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I think you are right, but then the title of the question and the tags are misleading.

Comment: Side note: Wouldn't `printf "%s\n" {A..Z} {a..z} | nl -ba` be an easier way to generate your example results?

Answer (score 6):

Go back to high school probability. With 26 bins, the distribution of the number of items `k` in any bin ought to be binomial (if `shuf` is working properly): B(k; 1000, 1/26). That is the probability of `k` successes in 1000 trials where the probability of success on any trial is 1/26.

The variance of the binomial `Var = np(1 - p) = 1000(1/26)(25/26) =~ 37`.

Now what's the variance of your result? That is `E(X^2) - (E(X))^2`. You can quickly plug the data into a Google Sheet or equivalent. It's 36.

So your result reflects only a tiny difference from the variance of perfectly random data. Its as "even" as nature predicts it should be.

The conclusion from the very limited info you've provided is that `shuf` is doing exactly what it's designed to do.

If you want certain songs to come up other than purely randomly, you can devise a weighting scheme that prefers some songs over others.  A really simple way is to put each song `i` in the original list in `W_i` copies where `W_i` is the desired relative weight. Then shuffle.  There are many other possible schemes.

[This kind of thing is why I have a good belly laugh every time someone says math isn't needed to be a computer programmer.]

Comment: Upvoted your answer as your explanation is much better than my answer, which gave no explanation on why there is nothing wrong here. No doubt that this is the correct answer.

Comment: This makes complete sense. Thanks for the thorough explanation. You've provided the math and archimiro has provided the examples (thanks to both of you). Now the only question is, why I do I always *feel* like shuffle is putting some type of mysterious preference on certain songs (the ones I feel like I hear more often than others). Probably need a psychologist to answer that one.

Comment: @mdaddy Imagining patterns in random data has been a plague on mankind for millennia. You're just the latest guy to arrive to the party. ;-)

Comment: Without good old statistics, physics and chemistry would have never gone much further than gunpowder... [**Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle**](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2013/nov/10/what-is-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle)

Comment: You should change binomial to [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) in your explanation, since there are 26 possible outcomes on each trial.

Answer (score 0):

This give me a nice distribution:

```
 cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-z | head -c 1000 | grep -o . | sort | uniq -c
```

Notice that as you increase the size of the sample you get a more accurate result:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-z | head -c 1000000 | grep -o . | sort | uniq -c
```

But I don't really thing there is anything wrong with `shuf`, I tried this:

```
for i in {1..1000};do printf "%s\n" {a..z} | shuf -n1 ;done | sort | uniq -c
```